# How to using join and left join mysql

Tags: mysql

i want to show my database using join and left join. but look like it not working well.

here what i try

```
SELECT ordercustline.QuantityOrdered,ordercustline.ProductID,ordercustline.UnitCustPrice,ordercustline.QuantityDelivered,ordercustline.Active,ordercustline.ProductNumber,products.ProductNumber as PN,products.id,pdt.ProductName,dbpjs.CodeName,ordercustline.id as oid, pdt.LanguageID 
  FROM ordercustline 
  LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = ordercustline.ProductID 
  LEFT JOIN producttexts as pdt ON pdt.ProductID = products.id 
  JOIN DiagnosisBPJS as dbpjs ON dbpjs.id = ordercustline.ProductNumber 
  WHERE ordercustline.OrderID = 20 AND ordercustline.Active = 2 AND pdt.LanguageID = 'en'
```

the problem is when `ordercustline.ProductID` have `null` value then the query will not working, i think it because `pdt.LanguageID = 'en'`.

when i delete it then the query is working good, but i want to filter the product with `pdt.LanguageID = 'en'`.

what i have to do to make it work even when `ordercustline.ProductID` have `null` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put you `pdt.LanguageID = 'en'` condition in `ONClausee` instead of `Where clause`

```
SELECT ordercustline.QuantityOrdered,ordercustline.ProductID,ordercustline.UnitCustPrice,ordercustline.QuantityDelivered,ordercustline.Active,ordercustline.ProductNumber,products.ProductNumber as PN,products.id,pdt.ProductName,dbpjs.CodeName,ordercustline.id as oid, pdt.LanguageID 
  FROM ordercustline 
  LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = ordercustline.ProductID 
  LEFT JOIN producttexts as pdt ON pdt.ProductID = products.id AND pdt.LanguageID = 'en'
  JOIN DiagnosisBPJS as dbpjs ON dbpjs.id = ordercustline.ProductNumber 
  WHERE ordercustline.OrderID = 20 AND ordercustline.Active = 2
```